# Exclude numbered section from toc

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to exclude a section from the table of contents, but would still to assign it a number and be able to refer to it. This was basically adressed [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=11333).

However, I also modified my section headers and **don't know how this modification can be taken into account** when typesetting the section that is excluded from the toc.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{\thesection}{8pt}{\large}

\begin{document}

\section*{\refstepcounter{section}\label{sec:A}\thesection Section A} % from link provided
\section*{\refstepcounter{section}\label{sec:B}\thesection\hspace{8pt} Section B}
\section{Section C}

\end{document}
```

The problem is visualised here:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is to exclude a section from the TOC, you need simply change the `tocdepth` before you write the section information to the TOC.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{8pt}{\large}
\newcommand{\restoretoc}{\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}}
\newcommand{\notocsection}[2][]{\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\section[#1]{#2}\restoretoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section A\label{sec:A}} 
\notocsection{Section B\label{sec:B}}
\section{Section C}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to adapted the spacing in every individual `\section*{}` you can define your own command for the space

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\myspace}{8pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{\thesection}{\myspace}{\large}

\begin{document}

    \section*{\refstepcounter{section}\label{sec:A}\thesection\hspace{\myspace}Section A} % from link provided
    \section*{\refstepcounter{section}\label{sec:B}\thesection\hspace{\myspace}Section B}
    \section{Section C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it does. But I was hoping for a way to not have to add the 8pt manually, as I would like to use this in various documents with differing layouts. Will change the question later accordingly

Comment: Modified the answer to have the `8pt` stored in only one place